# Validating form in Chrome extension popup not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

The Chrome extension I am making has a popup.html with a form like:

```
<head>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="myform" action="http://www.example.com/myurl.jsp" method="get" target="_blank">
  #<input type="text" size="10" name="numid" value="" />
  <input type="Submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

myscript.js is listed in manifest.json "background" and "content_scripts" sections:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["myscript.js"] }`
"js": ["jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "myscript.js"]
```

and myscript.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
  alert("alert!");
});
```

How can I have it display the alert() when I click the Go button or hit the enter key for the form?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the `popup.js` in `background` and `content_script` if you only intend to use it in a popup.

Alert is not showing because you can't show alerts from popup. Instead try:

- `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "Works!"` (this will replace the whole body of popup with a message)
- or use `console.log("Works!")` (this will output text to Developer Tools console - be sure to look into popup developer tools not current page developer tools though)

---

**Edit:** Your `myscript.js` seems invalid, you are missing `});`. Also, please mind that you may miss the result of code execution inside submit callback since page is immediately reloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
     alert("alert!");
  });
});
```

Comment: If forgot to add the `});` to the snippet, it's actually there in the file. I tried both your suggestions but it immediately brings up a new tab and doesn't display message. I have the dev tools console open but the new tab doesn't display the console.

Comment: As I mentioned, you may miss the result of code execution inside submit callback, because you are immediately redirected to another page. Try adding `return false;` at the end of callback: `$('#myform').submit(function(){... return false;})`. This will prevent submit from happening but you will actually see the result.

Comment: Hm.. are you sure you include jquery in your popup? You should have it in `<head>` before `script.js`. Don't you get any errors on the popup console?

Comment: Yes, both of your comments resolved this, thanks! I thought since the js was listed in background and content_scripts sections of manifest.json that it wasn't needed in the html `<head>` section.